# Where should I go for translations of mathematical texts?

Tags: soft-question

I am currently trying to read *Applications algébriques de la cohomologie de groupes. II: théorie des algèbres simples* by **J-P. Serre**. It is very hard for me to read this article since I'm not a native Frech speaker. Also normal traslation machines can only do so much for you if you need proper mathematical (scientific) texts translated. Now I don't think that MSE is the right place to constantly ask for translations, but I figured someone here might know a good site for translating math articles. This would really help me a lot.

**N.B.** I don't need a site/person that/who can translate entire articles for me, just small phrases/theorems.

In particular I need the translation of *Corollaire 2*.

Comment: If its a small paragraph, just ask it here!

Comment: @lhf It is in http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/item?id=SHC_1950-1951__3__A7_0 on page 7-02

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of a *propre commutant* and the part of the proof that is on page 7-03

Comment: I wasn't sure about *commutant* either. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutant .

Comment: And now to interpret the *propre* part...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original text is:

[image]
[image]

This translates to:

> Corollary 2. Let $L$ be a commutative subfield of an algebra $A$, which is simple, finite and central over $k$. Then $L$ is its own commutant if and only if $[A:k]=[L:k]^2$ or $L$ is the maximal commutative subring of $A$.

Here the *commutant* $L'$ of $L$ probably means the set of elements of $A$ that commute with every element of $L$. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutant).
Now the proof:

> Let $L'$ be the commutant of $L$ in $A$; since $L$ is commutative, $L'\supseteq L$. From theorem 9, it is clear that $L'=L$ is equivalent to:
>   $$
> [A:k]=[L:k]^2
> $$
>   On the other hand, if $L'=L$, every commutative subring of $A$ containing $L$ is inside $L'$, and so is equal to $L$, and $L$ is the maximal commutative subring of $A$.
>   Conversely, if $L$ is so, every element commuting with $L$ is in $L$, and $L'=L$.